# Plexe examples run

Tags: plexe

```
plexe:~% cd src/plexe/examples/platooning
plexe:~/src/plexe/examples/platooning% plexe_run -u Cmdenv -c Sinusoidal -r 2   zsh: command not found: plexe_run
zsh: exit 127   plexe_run -u Cmdenv -c Sinusoidal -r 2
```

I have installed the instant Plexe and followed the tutorial (http://plexe.car2x.org/tutorial) for the demonstration, but encountered the error messages as mentioned above.

Has anyone encountered a similar problem? Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the command `plexe_run` is not recognized by your shell. The error "zsh: command not found" typically means that the shell doesn't know where to find or how to execute the specified command.

The most common reason for this issue is that the command might not be installed or might not be included in your system's PATH variable.

If you're trying to run a simulation using the Plexe framework, make sure you have installed it correctly and that the `plexe_run` command is available in your environment. You might need to check the installation instructions or documentation for Plexe to ensure you've set it up properly.

Additionally, you can try to locate the `plexe_run` command by using the `find` command or checking the installation directory to ensure it exists and then either navigate to that directory or add it to your system's PATH variable for easier access.